# What does this error implies : "Warning: ldap_mod_add(): Modify: Type or value exists"

Tags: php, ldap

I'm using the ldap for 2 days (so I'm not really confident about this tool) for a project and I receive that error.

Here's the code :

```
$ldap_user = $this->container->getParameter('ldap_user');
            $ldap_pass= $this->container->getParameter('ldap_pass');
            $ldap_co = ldap_connect($this->container->getParameter('ldap_address'));
            if ($ldap_co) {
                ldap_set_option($ldap_co, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
                ldap_bind($ldap_co , $ldap_user, $ldap_pass);
                $sr =ldap_search($ldap_co, "ou=Users,dc=LOCALLAN,dc=OSAXIS,dc=FR", "uid=*");
                $userList = ldap_get_entries($ldap_co, $sr);
                $tmp = 0;
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($userList) - 1 ; $i++)
                {
                    if ($tmp < $userList[$i]['uidnumber'])
                        $tmp = $userList[$i]['uidnumber'];
                }
                $tmp[0]++;
                $userId['memberUid']=$user->getUsrLogin();
                ldap_mod_add($ldap_co, 'cn=Osaxis,ou=Groups,dc=LOCALLAN,dc=OSAXIS,dc=FR', $userId);
                $dn = "uid=".$user->getUsrLogin();
                $dn.= ",ou=Users,dc=LOCALLAN,dc=OSAXIS,dc=FR";
                $info['cn'] = $user->getUsrLogin();
                $info['displayname'] = $user->getUsrNom() . " " . $user->getUsrPrenom();
                $info['mail'] = $user->getUsrEmail();
                // $info['birthdate'] = str_replace("-", "/",$user->getUsrDateNaissance()->format('d-m-Y'));
                $info['entrydate'] = str_replace("-", "/",$user->getUsrDateEmbauche()->format('d-m-Y'));
                $info['gecos'] = "User";
                $info['gidnumber'] = "513";
                $info['objectClass'][0] = "top";
                $info['objectClass'][1] = "person";
                $info['objectClass'][2] = "organizationalPerson";
                $info['objectClass'][3] = "posixAccount";
                $info['objectClass'][4] = "shadowAccount";
                $info['objectClass'][5] = "inetOrgPerson";
                $info['objectClass'][6] = "entryDateOsaxis";
                $info['sn'] = $user->getUsrPrenom();
                $info['uidnumber'] = $tmp[0];
                $info['givenname'] = $user->getUsrNom();
                $info['homedirectory'] = "/home/".$user->getUsrLogin();
                $info['shadowlastchange'] = "16605";
                $info['shadowmax'] = "3650";
                $info['telephonenumber'] = $user->getUsrTelport();
                $info['userpassword'] = md5($user->getUsrPassword());
                ldap_add($ldap_co, $dn, $info);
                ldap_close($ldap_co);
```

At first I thought it was because I added `birthdate` while no field exists with this name in the ldap. But the error is still here after I removed the line. I also cleared the cache but the error is still here and not clear enough for me to understand what is the problem...

If anyone has a solution that would be awesome.

Comment: Tried ldap_mod_replace() instead?

Comment: It... Actually worked like a charm... ^^ I'll go see the doc about this to know a bit more about what it changes. But why using a function that "replace" instead of "add" which according to the manual is made to, well, add something new (which is my purpose) ? Anyway thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ldap_mod_add`, as the name implies, adds a value to an existing attribute (in addition to what it might already have). `ldap_mod_replace` simply replaces any value(s) the attribute may have with whatever you specify.

In this case, what the warning seems to be telling you is that the value you are attempting to add already exists as a value for the attribute. You don't get the same error with `ldap_mod_replace` because it doesn't care what values are already set for the attribute and just subs in whatever you specify.

What you probably should do is check the values of `memberUid` before adding to it (That seems to be the value triggering it anyway).